# Malfunction of the scope of a module public variable?

Tags: excel, vba

In this simple code the scope of two `Public` variables of `General` module (`gsOT` and `gsPath`) works fine. 
If `UF_Printer.CB_Ok_Click ()` form event call `General.CheckPath` function, variables are visible and has same value in both scopes, form and module, [as you can see in this screenshot of the inspection window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fcpgj.png)

```
Public gsOT As String
Public gsPath As String

Public Function CheckPath(ByVal sPath_I As String) As String
    gsOT = "1234"
    gsPath = sPath_I & "\"
    CheckPath = gsPath
End Function

'Ok command button in UF_Printer user form
Private Sub CB_Ok_Click()
    Dim PrintPath As String
    PrintPath = CheckPath("C:\PDM\Client")
    PrintPath = gsPath & gsOT
End Sub
```

But in a real environment, two variables (`gsOT` and `gsRuta`) also declared `Public` in `General` module, do not work the same when called from `Formulario_Printer.CB_Ok_click()` form event.

`gsOT` variable works correctly and has a value in `Formulario_Printer` form, but `gsRuta` is empty. 
And both are out of `General` module context when the application focus is on the form context. However, in the simple example they are in context and have the same value.

The code of the real environment is very complex to put it but the operation is the same as in the simple example: from a form I call a function of a module to check and fill some variables. I have taken some screenshots in case this can help.

1. [Before calling the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yt0se.png)
2. [While working on the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUoiy.png)
3. [After calling the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTjSS.png)

Comment: Tanks freeflow. In both cases (simple and real) I get the same suggestion for the two variables: Public field breaks encapsulation, consider exposing a property instead. But not errors or warnings.

Comment: Assignments are fine freeflow, only occur once in "General" module "CompruebaRuta" procedure. Thank you very much, I will use another approach and create new variables in the form